# Not displaying value from input in form

Tags: html, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to display the user ID from a database in a textbox. In the input I am trying to retrieve the user ID, which works, but when I try display it in a textbox it does not appear? The java part if my code is working but I am unsure how I can display the results set in a textbox? Any help much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JPage</title>
    </head>
    <body>

     <%
            try{
              String session_id =null;
        HttpSession session1=request.getSession(false); 
                  if(session1!=null){  
        session_id=(String)session1.getAttribute("name");  

        }

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/alt", "root", "");
       Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from register where uid='"+session_id+"'");
          rs.next();
          String uid = rs.getString("uid");
          %>

   <form action="register_1.jsp" method="post">

   <input   type="text"name="TestType" value="Chemical"> 
   <imput  type="text" value=" <%out.print(uid);%> " name="uid" >
   <input value="Create"   type="submit" class="btn" style="width: 100px;"> 

   </form>
                         <%
         }catch(Exception e){
          out.println(e);
         }

        %>

    </body>
</html>
`
```

Comment: Do not use db acces directlyy in a jsp. learn about three tier architecture. Also learn about prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Comment: `<imput ...` doesn't look right.

Comment: I agree with Jens. THis is fine for a quick Test, but should not go into something productive.
I highly recommend to use a connection pool, with the way above you are messing up your DB with a lot of unclosed connections. Also prepared statements are important in Web-Applications.
Then have a look at JSP with JSTL or look at JSF it makes your life much easier